# Open a pair of tabbed terminal windows with titles

Tags: command-line, ssh, gnome-terminal

I am constantly opening up a pair of terminal windows which I like to have on separate tabs that I then use to SSH to the same pair of servers. I then set the titles of each tab to be that of the server I am connecting to. This is something I do manually every day and would love to be able to automate it.

So I tried the following:

```
gnome-terminal --tab
gnome-terminal --tab
gnome-terminal -t hello
gnome-terminal -t=hello
gnome-terminal -t="hello"
gnome-terminal --title="hello"
gnome-terminal --title=hello
gnome-terminal --title='hello'
gnome-terminal --tab --title='hello'
```

None of these options were able to open a new terminal window in a tab or with the title set to "hello". I haven't even tried to tackle the problem of ssh-ing to the servers yet. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
gnome-terminal --tab -t "watch" -e "watch ps -ef" --tab -t "top" -e "top"
```

It seems that gnome-terminal ignores `--tab` if there is only one in the command line. You have to provide at least two `--tab` to have some effect.

The command to execute is given by `-e` or `--command`. I used `watch` and `top` in my example because they run indefinitely so the tabs will stay open. Once the command is done executing the tabs will close themselves. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512055/avoid-gnome-terminal-close-after-script-execution/3531426#3531426) for how to prevent the tabs from closing once the command is done executing.